# What is the most efficient way to delete from a table a with the composite key which is retrieved from table b?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I user INNER JOIN, but it doesn't seem to be efficient:

```
DELETE from table1 
FROM table1 as a INNER JOIN table2 as b 
ON b.pk1=a.pk1 
AND b.pk2=a.pk2
```

MERGE statement is pretty much the same case:

```
MERGE table1 AS target  
USING table2 AS source  
ON (target.pk1= source.pk1 AND target.pk2=source.pk2)  
WHEN MATCHED   
    THEN DELETE;
```

Is there any better ways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: both, and also using `exists`, will all result in (probably) the same execution plan, the two tables have to be joined on the two key columns. The selectivity of the data and suitable indexes will dictate how efficient it is.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, merge statement does a inner join behind the scene, just like the delete statement. There are no specific ways to improve the performance in this case. However, applying a proper combination of distribution type, partitioning and indexing could improve inner join performance.